# Get parameter from exe in C++

Tags: c++, parameters

As we know the Query String in web. It's key/value go with the website URL ex: abc.com?**myName=stack**

For example in PHP, if we want get value of the myName, just do this $_GET['myName']

So, in C++, how can I get it?

in C# I pass an parametter to an *.exe file ( this exe file is C++ code ).
In C++ code, how to get this parametter value .

Comment: Can you expand and give the context in which the c++ program runs

Comment: It arrives as a argument to your main method, doesn't it?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please review it. :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea about your situation, but surely you will have realize what parameters do you really need?

1. If you just need arguments from the command line, simple use the `char** argv` variable. In complicated cases you can use [GNU getopt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) or even [Boost::Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html) (the last is cross-platform);
2. If you are trying to access environmental variables, use standard [`getenv`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) functions.

Answer (score 2):

Build a console application with just the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   for(int i = 1; i != argc; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Assuming the name of the .exe is `mytest.exe`, execute it with some arguments, such as:

```
mytest.exe Hello there.
```

You should get the following output:

```
Hello
there.
```

Hope the simple example makes it clear as to how to process command line arguments in C++.

Comment: (I'm an C# programmer, thus i don't know many about VC++) 
Ah. I'm using VC++ MFC, how to get the parametter in an Dialog ?

Comment: I haven't used MFC at all. Can't help you there.

Comment: and argv[i] cant be stored inside char* nameObtained ? as i want to manipulate the name ...

Comment: @gumuruh yes you can.